# How to resolve dependency conflict of an SBT dependency?

Tags: dependencies, sbt

I have a project's **build.sbt** which is using :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.lerestau" % "killer-launcher" % "1.0.2",
   "com.lerestau" % "menu-starter" % "1.0.0"
)
```

**menu-starter** transitively downloading **"killer-launcher" % "0.0.8"** and Hence getting errors in current project. Is there any way to resolve this sort of conflict. I came up with **dependencyOverrides**, but that works if conflict is entirely binary. That didn't work. How to resolve in **SBT**?

Answer (score 5):

The following should get rid of the transitive dependency of menu-starter on the older killer-launcher version:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.lerestau" % "killer-launcher" % "1.0.2",
  "com.lerestau" % "menu-starter" % "1.0.0" exclude("com.lerestau", "killer-launcher"
)
```

More details can be found in [the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html) unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to link directly to the relevant section.

Comment: I am using a `class` that is defined in new Version i.e. **1.0.2** but it's not present in the old version (0.0.8). If I `exclude("com.lerestau","killer-launcher")`, it would throw `NoClassDefFoundError`, as it threw in my case.

Comment: menu-starter only includes version 0.8, so excluding that one shouldn't have an impact unless menu-starter depends on interfaces only available in 0.8

Comment: As per my understanding of you're saying "excluding that one shouldn't have an impact on **my project** ", that's correct for compilation. But at build time and when i tried to run this, got this "NoClassDefFoundError" Pointing to `com/lerestau/killer-launcher/Launcher$NewLauncher`. This **NewLauncher** is there in version **1.0.2** but not in **0.0.8**.

Comment: Sbt will, by default, choose the last version. In the cases where this didn't work (example that happened to us: someone including slf4j-classic in a library) getting rid of the "bad" dependency should solve it. 

If, however both have hard dependencies on their respective version and these versions are fundamentally incompatible then I don't see how this conflict can reasonably be resolved by any tool (be it Sbt, Maven, Gradle or what have you). 

Perhaps a [dependency graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) would provide clarity.